# Infinispan JPA CacheStore in server mode

Tags: jpa, caching, infinispan

Need to front an existing DataStore (RDBMS) with infinispan, with write-behind. Also we dont want to run Infinispan in embedded mode to avoid memory pressure on the existing application which needs to serve high volume. We would like to run a cluster of infinispan in server mode and connect our application using hotrod.

Since JDBCStore doesnt support custom schema, the only option is to use JPA based CacheStore, however looks like there is limitation of only allowing JPA store to work in embedded mode .. Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part of using JPA cache store with server is how to plug user classes into the server. This is necessary since JPA entities/collections need to be accessible for JPA cache store. It might be possible to do this by creating a module and plugging it into the server modules and having Infinispan JPA cache store modules depend on it. This might be doable but not something we encourage/support and requires deep understanding of Infinispan Server's module architecture.

My suggestion would be to stick to embedded use case and JPA cache store. To avoid memory issues, you could configure eviction so that only those recently used entries are kept in memory. You could also use off-heap container in Infinispan to offload data storage outside the heap and keep your application running smoothly.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The off-heap storage is a great idea and might work for us, will check on same. If you have handy links to sample configuration / usage for off-heap storage pls do share

Comment: Documentation on enabling off-heap can be found [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#storage_type).